# Stands/platforms for putting my desktop tower on the floor

Tags: desktop-computer, workspace

I need more desk space, so I want to move my desktop tower to the floor. Are there any platforms that I could just lay on the carpet? I want to make sure there's enough room underneath the case for ventilation, and not to have any issues with static etc.

Comment: ikea! :) http://www.ikea.com/no/no/catalog/products/30090438

Comment: My (then) girlfriend's entire freshmen dormitory floor flooded 1-2 inches deep because of a damaged toilet.  On the 14th floor.  Many noble computers died that day.  Take home lesson: buy a $3 wooden 2x4 and make a simple square stand.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like [this](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=floor+computer+stand&cid=3909432297628997841&sa=title#p).  It has wheels and is a little bit above the floor, giving your computer room to breathe.

Comment: Wheels are most bodaciously awesome on a computer stand.  You'll wonder what you ever did without them.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty - I recently picked one up for $10.

If you have an IKEA desk there are also under-hang supports although these wont take the wider cases you can get.

Despite that, I keep my computer on my desk, it seems to get far less dust in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go really cheep you can grab some extra level construction supplies, like  bricks and small pieces of lumber, that you or a friend have laying around. Clean them off and use that to make a stand for you computer. If you don't have access to this kind of thing it might not be worth it to you, but free is free.

Answer (score 0):

If your system functions fine sitting on your desk, you shouldn't have any problems with it sitting directly on the floor.  (Although be aware that it will accumulate dust internally at a higher rate).

Wheels are very useful for under-desk systems; makes pulling them out to get at the back connectors much easier (provided all the cables have enough slack).  Either add-on ones (see ephilip's answer), or if a new-/re-build is an option look at something like Akasa's Eclipse or Mirage cases where they're part of the deal.